# Mail class throw ClassFormatError: for javax/mail/Authenticator

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

**Welcome,**
I wrote simple test class form example [a JavaMail API – Sending email - by  mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) works perfectly but if i make separate class without main method like this:

```java
import com.sedzisz.papersoccer.PaperSoccer;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SendMail.class.getName());

private final Level logLevel;

private String propertyFileName;

private final Properties props;

public String getMessageText() {
    return messageText;
}

public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
    this.messageText = messageText;
}

public String getRecipientEmailAddress() {
    return recipientEmailAddress;
}

public void setRecipientEmailAddress(String recipientEmailAddress) {
    this.recipientEmailAddress = recipientEmailAddress;
}

private String messageText;

private String recipientEmailAddress;

public SendMail(String propertyFileName) {

    this.logLevel = Level.INFO;

    propertyFileName = "gmail.properties";
    if (propertyFileName != null) {
        this.propertyFileName = propertyFileName;
    }
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Set property file name [{0}]", propertyFileName);

    LOG.setLevel(logLevel);
    props = new Properties();
    loadProperties(propertyFileName);
}

public boolean sendMessageTo() throws FileNotFoundException {

    if (props.isEmpty()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Can't load propertis for mail connections");
    } else {

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        String userName = props.getProperty("username");
                        String password = props.getProperty("password");
                        LOG.log(logLevel, "User name [{0}], password [{1}]", new Object[]{userName, password});
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
                    }
                });

 //  Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
 //
        boolean succes = false;

 //            try {
 //                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(props.getProperty("username")));
 //                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
 //                        InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmailAddress));
 //                message.setSubject("Testing mail");
 //                message.setText("Weclome companion!,\n" + messageText
 //                        + "\n You wonn premmum code for redtube.com ;)");
 //                Transport.send(message);
 //                succes = true;
 //            } catch (AddressException ax) {
 //                LOG.info("Ble ble ble coś tam żle!!!");
 //            } catch (MessagingException me) {
 //                LOG.info("Jak wyżej tylko chodzi o maila");
 //            } finally {
            return succes;
  //            }
    }
}

private void loadProperties(String fileName) {

    ClassLoader loader = PaperSoccer.class.getClassLoader();
    System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "File encoding [{0}]", System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "File name [{0}]", fileName);

    InputStream is;
    try {
        loader.getResource(fileName);

        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Path to file [{0}]", loader.getResource(fileName));

        is = loader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        props.load(is);

        is.close();

        if (logLevel == Level.WARNING) {
            for (String key : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
                String value = props.getProperty(key);
                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "{0}= [{1}]", new Object[]{key, value});
            }
        }

        if (props.size() > 0) {
            LOG.log(logLevel, "Properties have [{0}] parameters", props.size());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "File [{0}] not found", fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Cannt read file [{0}]", fileName);
    }

}

}
```

Maven dependency:

```
<!-- Java Mail -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
 <!-- Java Mail -->
```

I got this error:

```
    java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/Authenticator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.sedzisz.papersoccer.activationMail.SendMailTest.hello(SendMailTest.java:44)
```

What is wrong with my code?

I tray do something like this:

```
private class MAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    public MAuthenticator() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        String userName = props.getProperty("username");
        String password = props.getProperty("password");
        LOG.log(logLevel, "User name [{0}], password [{1}]", new Object[]{userName, password});
        return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
    }
}
```

But i get this same error.

I tray do this:

```
    public boolean sendMessageTo(){
            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
                }
            };

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

    }
```

no results, simple unit test like:

```
    @Test
    public void testSendMail(){
            SendMail sm = new SendMail();
    }
```

throw always exception

Comment: *Constructor* should be declared with access specifier. i.e. `public SendEmail(String propertyFileName)`

Comment: True should be, but i still this same error.

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate an abstract class?

Comment: Sorry newbie what do you mean, are You think about Authenticator ? I don't understand why this same example work with main class ?

Comment: For other example use javax.mail from mail.jar my class tray use javax.mail from javaee-web-api (pom dependency)!

Comment: @Newbie Please see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/295637). You should not edit your posts to include `[SOLVED]` in the title.

Comment: I'm sorry it will not happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault i didint give you all information about project my pom is a little fatter and i have dependency to **javaee-web-api**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

i just move this

```
    <!-- Java Mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Java Mail -->
```

above **javaee-web-api** and problem disappeared.... almoste

```
public boolean sendMessageTo() {

    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            LOG.info("Create authenticator class and return PasswordAuthenticator");
            return new PasswordAuthentication(props.getProperty("username"), props.getProperty("username"));
        }
    };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

    boolean succes = false;

    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(props.getProperty("username")));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmailAddress));
        message.setSubject("Testing mail");
        message.setText("Weclome companion!,\n" + messageText
                + "\n You wonn premmum code for redtube.com ;)");
        Transport.send(message);
        succes = true;
    } catch (AddressException ax) {
        System.err.println(ax);
    } catch (MessagingException me) {
        System.err.println(me);
    } finally {
        return succes;
    }
}
```

Now i get another problem

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.sedzisz.papersoccer.activationMail.SendMailTest
gru 27, 2013 11:42:22 AM com.sedzisz.papersoccer.activationMail.SendMail <init>
INFO: Set property file name [gmail.properties]
gru 27, 2013 11:42:22 AM com.sedzisz.papersoccer.activationMail.SendMail loadProperties
INFO: File encoding [UTF-8]
gru 27, 2013 11:42:22 AM com.sedzisz.papersoccer.activationMail.SendMail loadProperties
INFO: File name [gmail.properties]
gru 27, 2013 11:42:22 AM com.sedzisz.papersoccer.activationMail.SendMail loadProperties
INFO: Path to file [file:/D:/source/java/NetBeansProjects/PaperSoccer/target/classes/gmail.properties]
gru 27, 2013 11:42:22 AM com.sedzisz.papersoccer.activationMail.SendMail$1 getPasswordAuthentication
INFO: Create authenticator class and return PasswordAuthenticator
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.042 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.sedzisz.papersoccer.activationMail.SendMailTest
hello(com.sedzisz.papersoccer.activationMail.SendMailTest)  Time elapsed: 1.996 sec  <<< FAILURE!
```

It should be easy to resolve!

Thank You :)

```
return new PasswordAuthentication(props.getProperty("username"), props.getProperty("username"));
```

Second parameter should be password not user name! everything work fine! Again thanks for you time ;)